# Document ends before end{document} command in latex

Tags: cv

I am trying to create my CV using someone else's template. It looks nice other than there is a random blank page at the front and my CV ends on the first page and it doesn't show everything that is typed. I have a feeling that it's a small mistake but I'm new to latex and cannot figure it out. I would appreciate any help! Many thanks!

The code is as follows:

```tex
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex


\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[vmargin=1.5cm, hmargin=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}% added <<<<<<<<<
\input{MySetup}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    
    %-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    % Left column
    %-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \begin{adjustbox}{valign=t}
        \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth} % Adapt width to your convenience
            %----------------------------------------------------
            % Please add a photo in 1x1 format
            \begin{center}
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \clip (0,0) circle (2cm) node {\includegraphics[width=4cm]{Simple-CV/rox.jpg}};
                \end{tikzpicture}
                
                \MySkip     % See MySetup.tex file
                
                %----------------------------------------------------
                {\LARGE \bfseries Roxanna Korologou-Linden}
                
                \MySkip     % See MySetup.tex file
                
                DOB: October 3, 1992\\
                Place of birth: Athens, Greece\\
                Place of residence: Bristol, United Kingdom \\
                
                \MySkip     % See MySetup.tex file
                
                \textcolor{ColorTwo}{\faEnvelopeO} 
                \myhref{mailto:your.email@mail.io}{rklinden@gmail.com} \\
                
                %\textcolor{ColorTwo}{\faChain} 
                %\myhref{https://your-web-page.io}{https://your-web-page.io}
            \end{center}
            
            \vfill
            
            
            %----------------------------------------------------
            \section*{Scientific interests}
            \raggedright
            \textcolor{ColorOne}{$\circ$} Genetic epidemiology \\
            \textcolor{ColorOne}{$\circ$} Ageing diseases \\
            \textcolor{ColorOne}{$\circ$} Functional and biomarker data \\
            \textcolor{ColorOne}{$\circ$} Lifecourse perspective
            
            \vfill
            
            %----------------------------------------------------
            \section*{Education}
            \begin{description}
                \raggedright
                \item [\normalfont \textcolor{ColorOne}{2021.}] \textbf{PhD in
                    Molecular, Lifecourse Genetic Epidemiology}\\
                University of Bristol\\
                Bristol, United Kingdom
                
                \item [\normalfont \textcolor{ColorOne}{2015.}] \textbf{Masters in 
                    Epidemiology}\\
                Imperial College London\\
                London, United Kingdom
                
                \item [\normalfont \textcolor{ColorOne}{2013.}] \textbf{Bachelor in Bioveterinary science (Hons)}\\ 
                University of Liverpool \\
                Liverpool, United Kingdom
            \end{description}
            \begin{description}
            \item [\normalfont \textcolor{ColorOne}{2013.}] \textbf{International Baccalaureate}\\ 
                Cairo American College \\
                Cairo, Egypt
            \end{description}
            
            \vfill
        \end{minipage}
    \end{adjustbox}
    %
    %
    %-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    % Vertical rule
    %-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %
    \hfill
    \begin{adjustbox}{valign=t}
        \begin{minipage}{0.05\textwidth} % Adapt width to your convenience
            \MyVerticalRule  % See MySetup.tex file
        \end{minipage}
    \end{adjustbox}
    \hfill
    %
    %-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    % Right column
    %-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \begin{adjustbox}{valign=t}
        \begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth} % Adapt width to your convienience
            \section*{Current situation}
            \begin{description}
                \raggedright
                \item[\normalfont \textcolor{ColorOne}{Oct. 2018 -- Dec. 2022.}] \textbf{PhD in Molecular, Genetic and Lifecourse Epidemiology }\\ \medskip
                
                My PhD proposal aims to investigate potential factors mediating the relationship between cognitive ability and Alzheimer's disease. In my research, I use brain magnetic resonance imaging data from various cohorts across the lifecourse, such as ABCD, Generation R, IMAGEN, ALSPAC, and UK Biobank. Techniques used for my thesis include TwoSample Mendelian randomization and meta-analytic techniques. \\
                
            \end{description}
            
            %----------------------------------------------------
            \section*{Experience}
            \begin{description}
                \raggedright
                \item[\normalfont \textcolor{ColorOne}{Jan. 2017 -- Oct. 2018.}] 
                \textbf{Research associate at the University of Bristol}\\ \medskip
                
                
                This research post focused on the investigation of the association between modifiable risk factors and Alzheimer’s disease (AD) in various cohort studies using causal inference methods. Projects have included examining the association between AD and cognitive and behavioural outcomes in the children of the Avon Longitudinal Study of Parents and Children (ALSPAC), by performing regression analyses using AD polygenic risk scores as exposures. I have also investigated the association between life course trajectories of cardiometabolic factors and the risk of AD in ALSPAC children using AD polygenic risk scores in random-effects multilevel models. Ongoing projects involve performing a phenome-wide association study with the aim of identifying potentially causal effects of AD, using the UK Biobank data on 500,000 participants. 
                
                \item[\normalfont \textcolor{ColorOne}{Sep. 2016 -- Jan. 2017.}] 
                \textbf{Research assistant at Metavirology Ltd.}\\ \medskip
                
                Updating Excel databases for HIV oral pre-exposure prophylaxis and Hepatitis C generic medicines, database analyses, creating and sending Powerpoint presentations to different organisations which provided us with data on a weekly basis. I was also involved in writing, submitting (HIV Glasgow, AASLD, CROI) and presenting abstracts at international conferences (HIV Glasgow 2016). Additional duties included performing meta-analyses of the clinical efficacy of originator Hepatitis C treatment for a systematic review, as well as analysing a clinical trial (MANET) of the efficacy and safety of darunavir for the treatment of HIV/AIDS.
                

            \end{description}
            \end{minipage} % added <<<<<<<<<
        \end{adjustbox} % added <<<<<<<<<<< 
    
        %-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        \hspace*{0.325\textwidth}\begin{adjustbox}{valign=t}
            \begin{minipage}{0.05\textwidth} % 
                \textcolor{ColorOne}{\rule{1pt}{0.4\textheight}}% adjust to proper length <<<<<<<<<<<<<
            \end{minipage}
        \end{adjustbox}
        \hfill
        %           %-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        %Left column
         \begin{adjustbox}{valign=t} % add more Experience <<<<<<<<<<<
            \begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
                    \begin{description}
                        \raggedright
                                        \item[\normalfont \textcolor{ColorOne}{Mar. 2015 -- Jun. 2015.}] \textbf{Research assistant (voluntary work) at PROLEPSIS Institute of Preventative Medicine at Maroussi, Athens)} \\
                    \medskip
This position included collecting and organising research questionnaires on the dietary habits of school children from poor areas of Greece, greatest affected by the economic crisis (2015). 
                        
                \end{description}
            \end{minipage} % added <<<<<<<<<
            \end{adjustbox} % added
            

            \section*{Publications}
            \begin{description}
                \raggedright
                
\item \underline{Korologou-Linden, R}, Leyden GM, Relton CL, Richmond RC, Richardson TG. \textbf{(2021)}. Multi-omics analyses of cognitive traits and psychiatric disorders highlights brain-dependent mechanisms. {\it Hum Mol Genet.}.

\item \underline{Korologou-Linden,R}, Xu, B, Coulthard, E, et al. \textbf{(2021)}.The bidirectional causal effects of brain morphology across the life course and risk of Alzheimer’s disease: A cross-cohort comparison and Mendelian randomization meta-analysis. {\it medRxiv}.
\item \underline{Korologou-Linden, R}, Leyden, G. M., Relton, C. L., et al. \textbf{(2021)}. Multi-omics analyses of cognitive traits and psychiatric disorders highlights brain-dependent mechanisms.{\it Hum. Mol. Genet}.
\item Davies, NM, \underline{Korologou-Linden, R}, Anderson, EL.\textbf{(2021)}. BMI is unlikely to be a plausible intervention target for reducing the incidence of dementia. {\it International Journal of Epidemiology}. \textbf{50}:3.
\item Papadopoulos, M, Patel, D, \underline{Korologou-Linden, R}, et al. \textbf{(2017)}. Safety and Efficacy of Parenteral Iron in Children with Inflammatory Bowel Disease {\it J Gastroentrology, Hepatol Endosc}.\textbf{2}:1–6.
\item Jamieson, E, \underline{Korologou-Linden, R}, Wootton, RE, et al. \textbf{(2020)}. Smoking, DNA Methylation, and Lung Function: a Mendelian Randomization Analysis to Investigate Causal Pathways. {\it Am J Hum Genet}.\textbf{106}:315–326.
\item Anderson, EL, Howe, LD, Wade, KH, Ben-Shlomo, Y, Hill, WD, Deary, IJ, Sanderson, E, Zheng, J, \underline{Korologou-Linden, R}, et al. \textbf{(2020)}. Education, intelligence and Alzheimer’s disease: evidence from a multivariable two-sample Mendelian randomization study. {\it Int J Epidemiol}.\textbf{49}:1163-1172.
\item \underline{Korologou-Linden, R}, Anderson, E, Millard LAC, et al.\textbf{(2019)} The causes and consequences of Alzheimer’s disease: A Mendelian randomization analysis. {\it medRxiv}. 
\item Anderson, EL, Richmond, RC, Jones, SE, Hemani, G, Wade, KH, Dashti, HS, Lane, JM, Heming, W, Saxena, R, Brumpton, B, \underline{Korologou-Linden, R}, et al. \textbf{(2020)}. Is disrupted sleep a risk factor for Alzheimer’s disease? Evidence from a two-sample Mendelian randomization analysis.{\it International Journal of Epidemiology}. \textbf{50}:3.
\item Pagoni, P, Leppert, B, Dardani, C, \underline{Korologou-Linden, R}, et al. \textbf{(2020)}. Exploring the causal effect of genetic liability for ADHD and autism on Alzheimer's disease: A two-sample Mendelian randomization study. {\it In review}.
\item Wang, X*, Nwokolo N*, \underline{Korologou-Linden,R}, et al. \textbf{(2017)}. InterPrEP: internet-based pre-exposure prophylaxis with generic tenofovir disoproxil fumarate/emtrictabine in London - analysis of pharmacokinetics, safety and outcomes. {\it HIV Med. England}.
\item Aloysius, I, Savage, A, Zdravkov, J, \underline{Korologou-Linden, R}, et al. \textbf{(2017)}. InterPrEP. Internet-based pre-exposure prophylaxis with generic tenofovir DF/emtricitabine in London: an analysis of outcomes in 641 patients. {\it Journal of Virus Eradication}. \textbf{3}:1-5.
\item Hill, A, Khwairakpam, G, Wang, J, Golovin, S, Dragunova, J, Smith, R, Houghton-Price, V, \underline{Korologou-Linden, R}, et al. \textbf{(2017)}. High sustained virological response rates using imported generic direct acting antiviral treatment for hepatitis C. { \it Journal of Virus Eradication}. \textbf{3}:193-196.
\item \underline{Korologou-Linden, R}, Anderson, EL, Jones, HJ, et al. \textbf{(2019)}. Polygenic risk scores for Alzheimer's disease, and academic achievement, cognitive and behavioural measures in children from the general population. {\it International Journal of Epidemiology}. 
\item \underline{Korologou-Linden, R}, O'Keeffe, L, Howe, LD et al. \textbf{(2019)}. Polygenic risk score for Alzheimer’s disease and trajectories of cardiometabolic risk factors in children. {\it Wellcome Open Res 2019}. \textbf{4}:125.

\item \underline{Korologou-Linden,R}, Xu, B., Coulthard, E., et al. \textbf{(2021)}. The bidirectional causal effects of brain morphology across the life course and risk of Alzheimer's disease: A cross-cohort comparison and Mendelian randomization meta-analysis.{\it medRxiv}.
    
\item Zheng, J, Xu, M, Walker, V,Yuan, J, \underline{Korologou-Linden,R}, et al. \textbf{(2021)}. Evaluating the efficacy and mechanism of metformin on Alzheimer’s disease in the general population: Mendelian randomization study. {\it Under review}.
 \end{description}
%----------------------------------------------------
\section*{Oral communications}
\begin{description}
\raggedright
             \item Hill, A, Khwairakpam G, Wang, J, Golovin, S, Dragunova, J, Smith, R, Houghton-Price, V, \underline{Korologou-Linden, R}, et al. Ninety-Six \$ SVR Rates Using Imported Generic DAAs for Patients with Hepatitis C. Conference on Retroviruses and Opportunistic Infections. February 2017. Seattle, WA, USA. Abstract 559.
\item \underline{Korologou-Linden, R}, Anderson, EL, Jones, HJ, et al. Polygenic risk scores for Alzheimer’s disease, and academic achievement, cognitive and behavioural measures in children from the general population presented at the Alzheimer’s society conference 2017.
\item \underline{Korologou-Linden, R}, Anderson, EL, Millard, LAC, Howe, LD et al. The causes and consequences of Alzheimer’s disease: A Mendelian randomization analysis presented at American Society of Human Genetics 2018 (San Diego) and the Mendelian randomization conference 2019 (Bristol). This was presented as a talk for Williams award nomination at the International Genetic Epidemiology Society.
\item \underline{Korologou-Linden, R}, Xu, B, Coulthard, E. (2021). The bidirectional causal effects of brain morphology across the life course and risk of Alzheimer’s disease: A cross-cohort comparison and Mendelian randomization meta-analysis. This abstract was presented virtually as a ten minute talk at the Oxford Genomics of Brain disorders conference. 
            \end{description}
            ---------------------------------------------------
\section*{IT skills}
\begin{description}
    \raggedright
    \item Advanced user of Microsoft Office (Excel, Word, Publisher, PowerPoint) and of applications such as Movie Maker. Other skills include the basic use of high- performance computing (Bluecrystal), using LINUX language.
\end{description}

\MySkip

\section*{Teaching}
\begin{description}
    \raggedright
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Tutoring on the polygenic risk scores lesson of the Genetic Epidemiology short course at the University of Bristol (June 2018 and May 2021)
        \item Tutoring on the Introduction to STATA course for the students enrolled in the Master's of Public Health course (September 2019).
    \end{itemize}
    
\MySkip

    \section*{Leadership}
\begin{description}
    \raggedright
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Organised and chaired the monthly meetings at the Integrative Epidemiology unit at my university (August 2020-September 2021). Duties including finding speakers across the different research themes of the unit and organising the meetings (in-person and virtually via Zoom).
    \end{itemize}
    
\end{description}

\MySkip

%----------------------------------------------------
            \begin{multicols}{2}
                \section*{Numerical tools}
                \begin{tabular}{ll}
                    R           & \SkillBull{$\bullet \bullet \bullet \, \circ$}\\
                    STATA       & \SkillBull{$\bullet \bullet \bullet \, \bullet$}\\
                    WinBUGS       & \SkillBull{$\bullet \bullet \bullet \, \circ$}\\
                    
                \end{tabular}
                
                \vfill\null \columnbreak  % Break column for new section
                
                \section*{Languages}
                \begin{tabular}{ll}
                    Arabic  & \SkillBull{$\bullet \bullet \circ \, \circ$} \\
                    English & \SkillBull{$\bullet \bullet \bullet \, \bullet$}\\
                    Greek       & \SkillBull{$\bullet \bullet \bullet \, \bullet$}\\
                    Spanish & \SkillBull{$\bullet \circ \circ \, \circ$}\\
                \end{tabular}
            \end{multicols}
            %----------------------------------------------------
            \LastUpdate
            %----------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Mysetup.tex:

```tex
% !TEX root = Simple-CV.tex
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Packages
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
% !TEX root = Simple-CV.tex
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Packages
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, urlcolor=ColorTwo]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Layout
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} 
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

%
% Color theme
%
\definecolor{ColorOne}{RGB}{0,110,140}  % Blue
\definecolor{ColorTwo}{RGB}{120,0,120}  % Mauve
%\definecolor{ColorTwo}{RGB}{140,100,0}     % Gold

\sectionfont{\color{ColorOne}} 
\subsectionfont{\color{ColorOne}} 

%
% Vertical line
%
\newcommand{\MyVerticalRule}{%
    \textcolor{ColorOne}{\rule{1pt}{\textheight}}
}

%
% Update
%
\newcommand{\LastUpdate}{%
\vfill
\centering \small
\textcolor{ColorOne}{Last updated: \monthname,~\the\year.}
}

%
% Skip
%
\newcommand{\MySkip}{
\vskip12pt
}

%
% Format hyperrefs
%
\newcommand{\myhref}[2]{%
\href{#1}{\textcolor{ColorTwo}{#2}}
}
%
% Format skill bullets
%
\newcommand{\SkillBull}[1]{%
\textcolor{ColorTwo}{#1}
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Question without a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) doesn't get enough attention. Try to make an MWE and add the code here.

Comment: Note that (1) I don't think the code is public. (2) we generally do not like going to external sources for example code (links rot over time and thus you're question will not be useful for others in the future)

Comment: You have loaded the `inputenc` package twice with different options which cause the error. Try removing one of them.

Comment: removing the second inputenc hasn't made a difference unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first page is build using three minipages. The last (right) minipage must end with

```
    \end{minipage}
\end{adjustbox}
```

A good point is before `\section*{Publications}`. The following pages will use the full text width.

```
               efficacy of originator Hepatitis C treatment for a systematic review, as well as analysing a clinical trial (MANET) of the efficacy and safety of darunavir for the treatment of HIV/AIDS.
            \end{description}
            \end{minipage} % added <<<<<<<<<
        \end{adjustbox} % added <<<<<<<<<<< 

            \section*{Publications}
            \begin{description}
                \raggedright
                
                \item \underline{Korologou-Linden, R}, Leyden GM, Relton CL, Richmond RC, Richardson TG. \textbf{(2021)}. Multi-omics analyses of cognitive traits and psychiatric disorders highlights brain-dependent mechanisms. {\it Hum Mol Genet.}.
```

[image: a]

**UPDATED** (after follow up)

To add other `item` under Education you must fill the left (first in the code) minipage.

Then  create the middle minipage (with the blue rule). In the example the rule was created using `\rule{<thickness>}{<lenght>}` with thickness = 1pt and length = 0.4 of the text height. Adjust this value to your liking. Try `\rule{1pt}{285pt}` for a shorter line.

If you wanted to add another `item` under Experience fill the   right (third in the code) minipage with the new item.

[image: C]

This is the complete code. (note that there are no blank lines between adjacent minipages)

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex


\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[vmargin=1.5cm, hmargin=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}% added <<<<<<<<<
\input{MySetup}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    
    %-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    % Left column
    %-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \begin{adjustbox}{valign=t}
        \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth} % Adapt width to your convenience
            %----------------------------------------------------
            % Please add a photo in 1x1 format
            \begin{center}
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \clip (0,0) circle (2cm) node {\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}};
                \end{tikzpicture}
                
                \MySkip     % See MySetup.tex file
                
                %----------------------------------------------------
                {\LARGE \bfseries Roxanna Korologou-Linden}
                
                \MySkip     % See MySetup.tex file
                
                DOB: October 3, 1992\\
                Place of birth: Athens, Greece\\
                Place of residence: Bristol, United Kingdom \\
                
                \MySkip     % See MySetup.tex file
                
                \textcolor{ColorTwo}{\faEnvelopeO} 
                \myhref{mailto:your.email@mail.io}{rklinden@gmail.com} \\
                
                %\textcolor{ColorTwo}{\faChain} 
                %\myhref{https://your-web-page.io}{https://your-web-page.io}
            \end{center}
            
            \vfill
            
            
            %----------------------------------------------------
            \section*{Scientific interests}
            \raggedright
            \textcolor{ColorOne}{$\circ$} Genetic epidemiology \\
            \textcolor{ColorOne}{$\circ$} Ageing diseases \\
            \textcolor{ColorOne}{$\circ$} Functional and biomarker data \\
            \textcolor{ColorOne}{$\circ$} Lifecourse perspective
            
            \vfill
            
            %----------------------------------------------------
            \section*{Education}
            \begin{description}
                \raggedright
                \item [\normalfont \textcolor{ColorOne}{2021.}] \textbf{PhD in
                    Molecular, Lifecourse Genetic Epidemiology}\\
                University of Bristol\\
                Bristol, United Kingdom
                
                \item [\normalfont \textcolor{ColorOne}{2015.}] \textbf{Masters in 
                    Epidemiology}\\
                Imperial College London\\
                London, United Kingdom
                
                \item [\normalfont \textcolor{ColorOne}{2013.}] \textbf{Bachelor in Bioveterinary science (Hons)}\\ 
                University of Liverpool \\
                Liverpool, United Kingdom
            \end{description}
            
            \vfill
        \end{minipage}
    \end{adjustbox}
    %
    %
    %-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    % Vertical rule
    %-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %
    \hfill
    \begin{adjustbox}{valign=t}
        \begin{minipage}{0.05\textwidth} % Adapt width to your convenience
            \MyVerticalRule  % See MySetup.tex file
        \end{minipage}
    \end{adjustbox}
    \hfill
    %
    %-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    % Right column
    %-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \begin{adjustbox}{valign=t}
        \begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth} % Adapt width to your convienience
            \section*{Current situation}
            \begin{description}
                \raggedright
                \item[\normalfont \textcolor{ColorOne}{Oct. 2018 -- Dec. 2022.}] \textbf{PhD in Molecular, Genetic and Lifecourse Epidemiology }\\ \medskip
                
                My PhD proposal aims to investigate potential factors mediating the relationship between cognitive ability and Alzheimer's disease. In my research, I use structural brain data from various cohorts across the lifecourse, such as ABCD, Generation R, IMAGEN, ALSPAC, and UK Biobank \\
                
                Here is a short description of your current project.
                
            \end{description}
            
            %----------------------------------------------------
            \section*{Experience}
            \begin{description}
                \raggedright
                \item[\normalfont \textcolor{ColorOne}{Jan. 2017 -- Oct. 2018.}] 
                \textbf{Research associate at the University of Bristol}\\ \medskip
                
                
                This research post focused on the investigation of the association between modifiable risk factors and Alzheimer’s disease (AD) in various cohort studies using causal inference methods. Projects have included examining the association between AD and cognitive and behavioural outcomes in the children of the Avon Longitudinal Study of Parents and Children (ALSPAC), by performing regression analyses using AD polygenic risk scores as exposures. I have also investigated the association between life course trajectories of cardiometabolic factors and the risk of AD in ALSPAC children using AD polygenic risk scores in random-effects multilevel models. Ongoing projects involve performing a phenome-wide association study with the aim of identifying potentially causal effects of AD, using the UK Biobank data on 500,000 participants. 
                
                \item[\normalfont \textcolor{ColorOne}{Sep. 2016 -- Jan. 2017.}] 
                \textbf{Research assistant at Metavirology Ltd.}\\ \medskip
                
                Updating Excel databases for HIV oral pre-exposure prophylaxis and Hepatitis C generic medicines, database analyses, creating and sending Powerpoint presentations to different organisations which provided us with data on a weekly basis. I was also involved in writing, submitting (HIV Glasgow, AASLD, CROI) and presenting abstracts at international conferences (HIV Glasgow 2016). Additional duties included performing meta-analyses of the clinical efficacy of originator Hepatitis C treatment for a systematic review, as well as analysing a clinical trial (MANET) of the efficacy and safety of darunavir for the treatment of HIV/AIDS.
            \end{description}
            \end{minipage} % added <<<<<<<<<
        \end{adjustbox} % added <<<<<<<<<<< 
    
            %---------------------------SECOND PAGE <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
       \begin{adjustbox}{valign=t}
        \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth} % Adapt width to your convenience
            \begin{description}
                \item [\normalfont \textcolor{ColorOne}{2013.}] \textbf{International Baccalaureate}\\ 
                Cairo American College \\
                Cairo, Egypt
            \end{description}
            
            \vfill
        \end{minipage}
    \end{adjustbox} \hfill  
    \begin{adjustbox}{valign=t}
            \begin{minipage}{0.05\textwidth} % 
                \textcolor{ColorOne}{\rule{1pt}{0.4\textheight}}% adjust to proper length <<<<<<<<<<<<<
            \end{minipage}
        \end{adjustbox}
        \hfill
        %
        %-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        % Right column  
        \begin{adjustbox}{valign=t} % add more Experience <<<<<<<<<<<
            \begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
                    \begin{description}
                        \raggedright
                    \item[\normalfont \textcolor{ColorOne}{Jan. 2015 -- Oct. 2016.}] 
                    \textbf{Research associate at the University of Bristol}\\ \medskip
                                
                    This research post focused on the investigation of the association between modifiable risk factors and Alzheimer’s disease (AD) in various cohort studies using causal inference methods. Projects have included examining the association between AD and cognitive and behavioural outcomes in the children of the Avon Longitudinal Study of Parents and Children (ALSPAC), by performing regression analyses using AD polygenic risk scores as exposures. I have also investigated the association between life course trajectories of cardiometabolic factors and the risk of AD in ALSPAC children using AD polygenic risk scores in random-effects multilevel models. Ongoing projects involve performing a phenome-wide association study with the aim of identifying potentially causal effects of AD, using the UK Biobank data on 500,000 participants. 
                        
                \end{description}
            \end{minipage} % added <<<<<<<<<
            \end{adjustbox} % added <<<<<<<<<<< 

            \section*{Publications}
            \begin{description}
                \raggedright
                
                \item \underline{Korologou-Linden, R}, Leyden GM, Relton CL, Richmond RC, Richardson TG. \textbf{(2021)}. Multi-omics analyses of cognitive traits and psychiatric disorders highlights brain-dependent mechanisms. {\it Hum Mol Genet.}.               
                \item \underline{Korologou-Linden,R}, Xu, B, Coulthard, E, et al. \textbf{(2021)}.The bidirectional causal effects of brain morphology across the life course and risk of Alzheimer’s disease: A cross-cohort comparison and Mendelian randomization meta-analysis. {\it medRxiv}.
                \item \underline{Korologou-Linden, R}, Leyden, G. M., Relton, C. L., et al. \textbf{(2021)}. Multi-omics analyses of cognitive traits and psychiatric disorders highlights brain-dependent mechanisms.{\it Hum. Mol. Genet}.
                \item Davies, NM, \underline{Korologou-Linden, R}, Anderson, EL.\textbf{(2021)}. BMI is unlikely to be a plausible intervention target for reducing the incidence of dementia. {\it International Journal of Epidemiology}. \textbf{50}:3.
                \item Papadopoulos M, Patel D, \underline{Korologou-Linden R}, et al. \textbf{(2017)}. Safety and Efficacy of Parenteral Iron in Children with Inflammatory Bowel Disease {\it J Gastroentrology, Hepatol Endosc}.\textbf{2}:1–6.
                \item Jamieson, E, \underline{Korologou-Linden, R}, Wootton, RE, et al. \textbf{(2020)}. Smoking, DNA Methylation, and Lung Function: a Mendelian Randomization Analysis to Investigate Causal Pathways. {\it Am J Hum Genet}.\textbf{106}:315–326.
                \item Anderson, EL, Howe, LD, Wade, KH, Ben-Shlomo, Y, Hill, WD, Deary, IJ, Sanderson, E, Zheng, J, \underline{Korologou-Linden, R}, et al. \textbf{(2020)}. Education, intelligence and Alzheimer’s disease: evidence from a multivariable two-sample Mendelian randomization study. {\it Int J Epidemiol}.\textbf{49}:1163-1172.
                \item \underline{Korologou-Linden, R}, Anderson, E, Millard LAC, et al.\textbf{(2019)} The causes and consequences of Alzheimer’s disease: A Mendelian randomization analysis. {\it medRxiv}. 
                \item Anderson, EL, Richmond, RC, Jones, SE, Hemani, G, Wade, KH, Dashti, HS, Lane, JM, Heming, W, Saxena, R, Brumpton, B, \underline{Korologou-Linden, R}, et al. \textbf{(2020)} Is disrupted sleep a risk factor for Alzheimer’s disease? Evidence from a two-sample Mendelian randomization analysis.{\it International Journal of Epidemiology}. \textbf{50}:3.
                \item Pagoni, P, Leppert, B, Dardani, C, \underline{Korologou-Linden, R}, et al. \textbf{(2020)} Exploring the causal effect of genetic liability for ADHD and autism on Alzheimer's disease: A two-sample Mendelian randomization study. {\it In review}.
                \item Wang, X*, Nwokolo N*, \underline{Korologou-Linden,R}, et al. \textbf{(2017)}. InterPrEP: internet-based pre-exposure prophylaxis with generic tenofovir disoproxil fumarate/emtrictabine in London - analysis of pharmacokinetics, safety and outcomes. {\it HIV Med. England}.
                \item Aloysius, I, Savage, A, Zdravkov, J, \underline{Korologou-Linden, R}, et al. \textbf{(2017)}. InterPrEP. Internet-based pre-exposure prophylaxis with generic tenofovir DF/emtricitabine in London: an analysis of outcomes in 641 patients. {\it Journal of Virus Eradication}. \textbf{3}:1-5.
                \item Hill, A, Khwairakpam, G, Wang, J, Golovin, S, Dragunova, J, Smith, R, Houghton-Price, V, \underline{Korologou-Linden, R}, et al. \textbf{(2017)}. High sustained virological response rates using imported generic direct acting antiviral treatment for hepatitis C. { \it Journal of Virus Eradication}. \textbf{3}:193-196.                                    
                \item \underline{Korologou-Linden, R}, Anderson, EL, Jones, HJ, et al. \textbf{(2019)}. Polygenic risk scores for Alzheimer's disease, and academic achievement, cognitive and behavioural measures in children from the general population. {\it International Journal of Epidemiology}. 
                \item \underline{Korologou-Linden, R}, O'Keeffe, L, Howe, LD et al. \textbf{(2019)}. Polygenic risk score for Alzheimer’s disease and trajectories of cardiometabolic risk factors in children. {\it Wellcome Open Res 2019}. \textbf{4}:125.
                \item \underline{Korologou-Linden,R}, Xu, B., Coulthard, E., et al. \textbf{(2021)} The bidirectional causal effects of brain morphology across the life course and risk of Alzheimer's disease: A cross-cohort comparison and Mendelian randomization meta-analysis.{\it medRxiv}.
                \item Zheng, J, Xu, M, Walker, V,Yuan, J, \underline{Korologou-Linden,R}, et al. \textbf{(2021)}. Evaluating the efficacy and mechanism of metformin on Alzheimer’s disease in the general population: Mendelian randomization study. {\it Under review}.
            \end{description}
            %----------------------------------------------------
            \section*{Oral communications}
            \begin{description}
                \raggedright
                \item \underline{Korologou-Linden, R}, Second Author, N., Third Author, N. et al. \textbf{(2019)} The title of a talk you did. {\it Conference}, November 16, 2006, City, Country.
            \end{description}
            ----------------------------------------------------
            \section*{Another section}
            \begin{description}
                \raggedright
                \item Something you want to include in your CV
            \end{description}

            
            \MySkip
            
            \newpage
            %----------------------------------------------------
            \begin{multicols}{2}
                \section*{Numerical tools}
                \begin{tabular}{ll}
                    R           & \SkillBull{$\bullet \bullet \bullet \, \circ$}\\
                    STATA       & \SkillBull{$\bullet \bullet \bullet \, \bullet$}\\
                    
                \end{tabular}
                
                \vfill\null \columnbreak  % Break column for new section
                
                \section*{Languages}
                \begin{tabular}{ll}
                    Arabic  & \SkillBull{$\bullet \bullet \circ \, \circ$} \\
                    English & \SkillBull{$\bullet \bullet \bullet \, \bullet$}\\
                    Greek       & \SkillBull{$\bullet \bullet \bullet \, \bullet$}\\
                    Spanish & \SkillBull{$\bullet \circ \circ \, \circ$}\\
                \end{tabular}
            \end{multicols}
            %----------------------------------------------------
            \LastUpdate
            %----------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

To add only a new item under Education use

```
%---------------------------SECOND PAGE <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \begin{adjustbox}{valign=t}
        \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth} % Adapt width to your convenience
            \begin{description}
                \item [\normalfont \textcolor{ColorOne}{2013.}] \textbf{International Baccalaureate}\\ 
                Cairo American College \\
                Cairo, Egypt
            \end{description}
            
            \vfill
        \end{minipage}
    \end{adjustbox} 
        \hfill  
    \begin{adjustbox}{valign=t}
            \begin{minipage}{0.05\textwidth} % 
                \textcolor{ColorOne}{\rule{1pt}{60pt}}% adjust to proper length <<<<<<<<<<<<<
            \end{minipage}
        \end{adjustbox}
        \hfill          
        \hspace*{0.6\textwidth}
        %%**************
        
        \section*{Publications}
            \begin{description}
```

[image: d]

Comment: Many thanks for your help. :-)

Comment: Is there any way to make the line height shorter on the second page? Also, I want to include my high school education but it gets cut off. I've edited my code above for you to see. Many thanks

Comment: @rkl Please see  the updated answer.